# C# - Calculate Binary Offset for Given Data

Tags: c#, offset, binary-data

I am identifying the offset of a given piece of data within a NAND dump. The piece of data I am trying to identify is the following - 'TitleId'.

https://github.com/Thealexbarney/LibHac/blob/master/src/LibHac/IO/Save/Header.cs

```
public class ExtraData
{
    public ulong TitleId { get; }
    public Guid UserId { get; }
    public ulong SaveId { get; }
    public SaveDataType Type { get; }

    public ulong SaveOwnerId { get; }
    public long Timestamp { get; }
    public long Field50 { get; }
    public uint Field54 { get; }
    public long DataSize { get; }
    public long JournalSize { get; }

    public ExtraData(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        TitleId = reader.ReadUInt64();
        UserId = ToGuid(reader.ReadBytes(0x10));
        SaveId = reader.ReadUInt64();
        Type = (SaveDataType)reader.ReadByte();
        reader.BaseStream.Position += 0x1f;

        SaveOwnerId = reader.ReadUInt64();
        Timestamp = reader.ReadInt64();
        Field50 = reader.ReadUInt32();
        Field54 = reader.ReadUInt32();
        DataSize = reader.ReadInt64();
        JournalSize = reader.ReadInt64();
    }
```

Do you know how I could get the offset of that titleid? I'm not particularly skilled at c#, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean offset? Offset into what, or offset from what?

Comment: The offset is from the start of the binary file, and the offset of the titleid is what i desire.

Comment: Seems to be position 0x6D8, https://github.com/Thealexbarney/LibHac/blob/master/src/LibHac/IO/Save/Header.cs#L71

Comment: Ok so saying i was trying to access that specific offset in say HXD hex viewer, how would i find it?

Comment: Go to line 6D0, then it is the 9th value on that line (8 --> 9 because 6d0 is the first item, 6d1 is the second, etc.)

Comment: OK, i've done that. The characters discovered at that position are:

Comment: A0 64 0D 80 23 00 01 55 BE D0 18 B3 80 01 10 8F 60 05 65 E9 98 30 0C

Comment: So the first 8 pairs there which are all zero, is that number, which means TitleId is 0.

Comment: Erm sorry, A0 was the first character. (the one 9 bytes in)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192444/discussion-between-dipl0-and-lasse-vagsaether-karlsen).

Comment: So the number is 0x55010023800d64a0. Now you need to figure out what that number means. Assuming my original assumption about the offset was correct that is.